# How to convert `if condition` to `switch` method

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

How can I write this `if condition` in `switch` method?

```
if( $k != 'pg_id' && $k != 'pg_tag' && $k != 'pg_user' )
{
     $result = $connection->run_query($sql,array(...));
}
```

to...?

```
switch($k)
{
case 'pg_id': false;
case 'pg_tag': false;
case 'pg_user': false;
default:
   $result = $connection->run_query($sql,array(...));

}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry I think I didn't make it clear earlier, below is how I want to use it,

```
$editable_fields = array(
    'pg_id',
    'pg_url',
    'pg_title',
    'pg_subtitle',
    'pg_description',
    'pg_introduction',
    'pg_content_1',
    'pg_content_2',
    'pg_content_3',
    'pg_content_4',
    'pg_backdate',
    'pg_highlight',
    'pg_hide',
    'pg_cat_id',
    'ps_cat_id',
    'parent_id',
    'tmp_id',
    'usr_id'
);

$sql_pattern = array();

foreach( $editable_fields as $key )
{
    if( $key != 'pg_id' && $key != 'pg_tag' && $key != 'pg_user'  ) $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?";
}
```

as you can see I repeated the condition there -

```
if( $key != 'pg_id' && $key != 'pg_tag' && $key != 'pg_user'  )
```

and it may grow long at some point.

Comment: That kind of fall-through, I don't know you can convert.

Comment: Wouldn't an `in_array` be more readable/portable/configurable?

Comment: @Wrikken you're right, but I suggest `!in_array` :)

Comment: sorry for not making it clear - have a look on my edit above. I think I can have the `break` there because it will stop the loop....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Borrowing from a previous question which I believe spawned this one - [A short-cut to update a table row in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893194/a-short-cut-to-update-a-table-row-in-the-database/))

```
$editable_fields = array(
  'pg_url' ,
  'pg_title' ,
  ...
);
/* These are the fields we will use the values of to match the tuple in the db */
$where_fields = array(
  'pg_id' ,
  'pg_tag' ,
  'pg_user' ,
  ...
);

$form_values = array();
$sql_pattern = array();
foreach( $editable_fields as $k ){
  if( $k != 'pg_id'
      && isset( $_POST[$k] ) ){
    $form_values[$k] = $_POST[$k];
    // NOTE: You could use a variant on your above code here, like so
    // $form_values[$k] = set_variable( $_POST , $k );
    $sql_pattern[] = "$k = ?";
  }
}
$where_values = array();
$where_pattern = array();
foreach( $where_fields as $k ){
  if( isset( $_POST[$k] ) ){
    $where_values[$k] = $_POST[$k];
    // NOTE: You could use a variant on your above code here, like so
    // $form_values[$k] = set_variable( $_POST , $k );
    $where_pattern[] = "$k = ?";
  }
}

$sql_pattern = 'UPDATE root_pages SET '.implode( ' , ' , $sql_pattern ).' WHERE '.implode( ' , ' , $where_pattern );

# use the instantiated db connection object from the init.php, to process the query
$result = $connection->run_query($sql_pattern,array_merge(
    $form_values ,
    $where_values
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` to prevent follow through to next case:

```
switch($k)
{
case 'pg_id':
case 'pg_tag':
case 'pg_user':
  // any match triggers this block; break causes no-op
  break;
default:
  $result = $connection->run_query($sql,array(...));
}
```

I'm not sure why you want to use a switch statement for this though.

If it's for readability, you could try this instead:

```
if($k != 'pg_id' &&
   $k != 'pg_tag' &&
   $k != 'pg_user')
{
  $result = $connection->run_query($sql,array(...));
}
```

Comment: sorry for not making it clear - have a look on my edit above. I think I can have the `break` there because it will stop the loop....

Comment: Yes, you can still use `break` inside a `switch` statement inside a `foreach` loop. By default `break` will only break out of the inner-most scope. You can tell it to break out of multiple scopes by adding the number of scopes after it (e.g. `break 2;`) but you do not want to do that here.

Answer (score 0):

A switch condition is likely to be faster (jump table) and a bit easier to read. You can skip the break; if the result of the condition is the same and an improved syntax is to use curly braces inside each condition:

```
switch ($k)
{
 case 'pg_id':
 case 'pg_tag':
 case 'pg_user': {
 break;
 }
 default: {
   $result = $connection->run_query($sql,array(...));
 }
}
```

Comment: To state that using braces is "the right syntax" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: What's your reason? This is a new information to me, too and I love it.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "the right syntax"? Best practice, _arguably_. Widespread? Absolutely not. A required and proper part of PHP syntax? No way.

Comment: Please be kind to me I'm not that veteran but I don't know you and I told you this is a NEW INFORMATION to me. From what I see it doesn't hurt the eye and maybe the php tokenizer work's a bit faster. Did you know that BIG LETTERS have a purpose in books (I know internet)? In german language there are many big letters and it's not easy to learn... I know 3 other languages but they all looks like english when it come to BIG LETTER.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about. I am talking about your assertion that "the right syntax is to use curly braces inside each condition"; I don't see where "BIG LETTERS" come into it.

Comment: @Toma: No problem, but it works and it produce the same result. So why not?

Comment: Absolutely! I often use it myself. That's a far cry from "the right syntax is to use [it]", which implies that it's required.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear - have a look on my edit above. I think I can have the `break` there because it will stop the loop....