# How can I tidy multiple if condition for readability?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

How can I tidy multiple if condition for readability?

For instance,

```
if( $key != 'pg_id' && $key != 'pg_tag' && $key != 'pg_user'  )
```

This confuses me when the items in that condition grow longer.

It was used in this kind of situation below - `foreach()`,

```
$editable_fields = array(
    'pg_id',
    'pg_url',
    'pg_title',
    'pg_subtitle',
    'pg_description',
    'pg_introduction',
    'pg_content_1',
    'pg_content_2',
    'pg_content_3',
    'pg_content_4',
    'pg_backdate',
    'pg_highlight',
    'pg_hide',
    'pg_cat_id',
    'ps_cat_id',
    'parent_id',
    'tmp_id',
    'usr_id'
);

$sql_pattern = array();

foreach( $editable_fields as $key )
{
    if( $key != 'pg_id' && $key != 'pg_tag' && $key != 'pg_user'  ) $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?";
}
```

I was thinking using [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906603/how-to-convert-if-condition-to-switch-method) but I think I was wrong!

Comment: you can use the [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if (!in_array($key, array('pg_id', 'pg_tag', 'pg_user'))
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be to put each condition on it's own line:

```
foreach( $editable_fields as $key )
{
    if( $key != 'pg_id' && 
        $key != 'pg_tag' && 
        $key != 'pg_user'  )
    { 
        $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?";
    }
}
```

I find this clarifies these types of compound conditions for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, use line-breaks:

```
if( $key != 'pg_id' &&
    $key != 'pg_tag' &&
    $key != 'pg_user'
 ){
    $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?";
}
```

Makes it more readable.

A `switch`-statement is meant to test only for one condition. Like if you would check for a number.

```
$number = 12;
switch($number){
  case 1:
    // Do stuff...
  case [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either spread it out:

```
if(
    $key != 'pg_id' && 
    $key != 'pg_tag' && 
    $key != 'pg_user'
) {
    /* code here */
    $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?"
}
```

... or use a switch statement

```
switch ($key) {
    default:
        /* code here */
        $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?"
        break;
    case 'pg_id':
    case 'pg_tag':
    case 'pg_user':
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor into a function with a name that describes its purpose:

```
function KeyIsNotMatch($key) {
    if( $key != 'pg_id' && $key != 'pg_tag' && $key != 'pg_user'  )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

foreach( $editable_fields as $key )
{
    if (KeyIsNotMatch($key)) $sql_pattern[] = "$key = ?";
}
```